# Adobe RGB Monitor behaves like sRGB under Xorg & HW Acceleration

Tags: xorg, wayland, color-management

Having a monitor that supports 100% of Adobe RGB color space. Used it for a while with Xorg and NVIDIA GPU after I found out that effective color gamut used was sRGB.

I have noticed that with disabled hardware acceleration, colors on Xorg are just fine - Adobe RGB is being covered. I've also tried using Wayland, and since NVIDIA GPU doesn't support running Wayland, I have tried installing an AMD GPU, and it worked just fine. All colors were just right while having the HW acceleration enabled.

Since my monitor is 27" one, using it becomes uncomfortable if 150% fractional scaling is not enabled. Unfortunately, fractional scaling as it is works REALLY BAD under Wayland. A lot of programs like Chromium are blurred, which also make Electron apps blurred as well.

Since blurry Chromium is a wontfix issue, how to get Xorg w/ HW acceleration actually displaying Adobe RGB color?

**EDIT:** Not sure, but is this something related to 8 and 10-bit color?

**EDIT 2**: Switching Chrome Color Profile from "Default" to "sRGB" colorized Chrome, but all other applications are still having wrong color.

**EDIT 3:** `--force-color-profile=srgb` flag looks to be colorizing Electron-based applications like VSCode and Discord.

Answer (score 0):

I use the monitor, my own profile.
Sample: LG monitor / MP59G
x11 and NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650]

nvidia x server settings use OpenGL settings High Quality and

[image]

Comment: I'm currently using an AMD GPU, and afaik while I was using NVIDIA GPU I had full color range turned on.

Comment: Plugged an NVIDIA GPU back in, and it doesn't work. The color range is on "Full" by default, and I still see sRGB colors... :(